# При записи в CSV файл дублируются заголовки

Tags: python, csv

Столкнулся с такой проблемой,  пытаюсь записать значения в файл CSV, но с каждой итерацией помимо данных записываются и заголовок

файл откуда я беру данные:

```
{'CardNumber': '4908479223533705', 'ContractType': 'No', 'NameSurname': 'MELIS RAY', 'PersonalCode': '290491-14236'}
{'CardNumber': '4208450200514387', 'ContractType': 'Yes', 'NameSurname': 'CORTEX AUTOLT', 'PersonalCode': '39104299168'}
{'CardNumber': '4208450200514395', 'ContractType': 'Yes', 'NameSurname': 'CORTEX AUTOLT', 'PersonalCode': '39104299168'}
```

```
import csv
import ast

def contract_lv(ddict):
    with open("contract_lv.csv", "a+", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerow(["CardNumber","ContractType","NameSurname","PersonalCode"])
        for k,v in ddict.items():
            print(v, file=f, end=';')


with open("csv_file.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        ddict = ast.literal_eval(line)
        if ddict["ContractType"] == "Yes":
            # print(ddict['CardNumber'])
            contract_lv(ddict)
```

на выходе в файле csv получаю следующее:

```
CardNumber;ContractType;NameSurname;PersonalCode
4208450200514387;Yes;CORTEX AUTOLT;39104299168;CardNumber;ContractType;NameSurname;PersonalCode
4208450200514395;Yes;CORTEX AUTOLT;39104299168;
```

почему после первой строки в файле csv выводится заголовок?

Comment: Вы же сами вызываете `writer.writerow(` в `contract_lv`, а `contract_lv` у вас вызывается для каждой строки. Нужно это сделать один раз до цикла по `lines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку:

```
import csv
import ast

def contract_lv(ddict, write_header):
    with open("contract_lv.csv", "a+", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
        if write_header:
            writer.writerow([
                "CardNumber",
                "ContractType",
                "NameSurname",
                "PersonalCode"
            ])
        for k,v in ddict.items():
            print(v, file=f, end=';')
        print(file=f)

with open("csv_file.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    write_header = True
    for line in lines:
        ddict = ast.literal_eval(line)
        if ddict["ContractType"] == "Yes":
            # print(ddict['CardNumber'])
            contract_lv(ddict, write_header)
            write_header = False
```

Я добавил переменную `write_header`, которая будет сообщать функции `contract_lv`, что нужно вывести заголовок, и функция будет это делать только при первом обращении. Кроме того, после вывода всей строки с данными, нужно не забывать переводить строку, для этого добавлен `print()`.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку,  но добавленный `print()`  не переводит строку.

Comment: Поправил. Там конечно тоже надо в файл печатать, а не просто так